# for loop not running in C plus plus program, without showing any error - CLOSED

Tags: visual-c++

It is a very simple program and I have just started learning c++ but the for loop is not working in this program. can anyone tell me why the for loop in this c++ program is not running?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class PrimeNo
{
    int a;
    int c;
public:
    // function to check prime number
    void chk_Prime(void)
    {
        cout << "Enter the number: " << endl;
        cin >> a;
        c=a/2; // to store the condition
        for (int i = 2; i < c; ++i)
        {
            if (a == 0 || a == 1) 
            {
                cout << "The number is not a prime number" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else if (a % i == 0) 
            {
                cout << "This number is not a prime number" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else //if upper conditions are false a number is a prime number
            {
                cout << "This number is a prime number" << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    PrimeNo Num;
    Num.chk_Prime();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What values for "a" are you inputting? This loop won't run for anything less than 5.

Comment: And when it runs, it only makes one iteration, as all three branches of the `if` statement inside end with `break`

Comment: I tested your code and I do not see any problem. Could you please elaborate?
What do you mean by "can anyone tell me why the for loop in this c++ program is not running?" Under what condition? Step by step, please.
Windows 10, Visual Studio 2022

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.